# Global Variable NOT working - Node 14.15.3

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var myVariable = 3;
console.log('global', globalThis.myVariable);
```

I tried running the code using `node file.js`, but keep getting the result:

> global undefined

Can someone explain to me what exactly is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find this from [Node documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global):

> In browsers, the top-level scope is the global scope. This means that within the browser var something will define a new global variable. In Node.js this is different. The top-level scope is not the global scope; var something inside a Node.js module will be local to that module.

and [Global object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object):

> In JavaScript, there's always a global object defined. In a web browser, when scripts create global variables defined with the var keyword, they're created as members of the global object. (In Node.js this is not the case.)

It mean that when you declare `var myVariable = 3;` it doesn't go into the node `global` object, you can try to print `global` object out.

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign value to globalThis variable

```
globalThis.myVariable = 3;
console.log('global', globalThis.myVariable);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Node Js scoping, any variable declared in the root of a module (a particular JS file) is a module-level variable.

```
var test = 'This string is global to this module';

function foo() {
   console.log(test);
}
```

Node Js also has the [Global Namespace Object](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global).

This object is accessible in any module.

```
 global.test = 'This string iscan be accessed by any module via the gloabl namespace object';

function foo() {
   console.log(global.test);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var global.myVariable = 3;
console.log('myVariable')
```

I did not check the code though